# Multiple validation in one rule using FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm tring to build a validation rule using FluentValidation lib.

When I use the first part of the code bellows, it works as expected; but when I use the second part, only the first validation is executed, ignoring the last two validation rules.

The second part is not supposed to work? Am I doing something wrong?

```cs
// first part -- it works
RuleFor(c => c.Field).RequiredField().WithMessage(CustomMsg1);
RuleFor(c => c.Field).ValidateField().WithMessage(CustomMsg2);
RuleFor(c => c.Field).IsNumeric().WithMessage(CustomMsg3);

// second part -- validates only the first rule
RuleFor(c => c.Field)
    .RequiredField().WithMessage(CustomMsg1)
    .ValidateField().WithMessage(CustomMsg2)
    .IsNumeric().WithMessage(CustomMsg3);
```

Comment: FluentValidation version: 9.5.3

Answer (score 2):

You can specify FluentValidator's cascading behavior with the CascadeMode enum.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html#setting-the-cascade-mode).

The default behavior should be the one you need, but if it works differently without setting the CascadeMode, maybe the default value is globally set somewhere in your project.

Configuring the default value globally looks like this:

```
ValidatorOptions.Global.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
```

Your code with the default value set above should look something like this:

```
RuleFor(c => c.Field)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.Continue)
    .RequiredField().WithMessage(CustomMsg1)
    .ValidateField().WithMessage(CustomMsg2)
    .IsNumeric().WithMessage(CustomMsg3);
```

Comment: you should mention that `CascadeMode.Continue` is the default. So you can omit it... I.e the OP's code should work. but it doesn't.

Comment: You can set the default behavior globally, maybe it is set to Stop somewhere in his project. But you are right, I edited the answer.

Comment: I understand that the cascade mode controls the execution when the validation fails, right? But... using the second part of my code, when the first validation succeed, it doesn't execute the other two validations.